# Is there a way to constantly update a graph figure while a switch is on in Dash Plotly Python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a function that updates the figure of a graph using an algorithm, and a callback function to return the graph's figure (among many other things). This is the basic idea:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    randomfunction(i)
    return plot
```

How can I update the graph without breaking the loop? I've tried using yield instead of return to no avail as the callback does not expect a generator class to be output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the accepted answer certainly works, there is another way to do it for anyone who may want to do this without external storage.

There is a Dash Core Component called `dcc.Interval` that you can use to constantly trigger a callback, within which you can update your graph.

For example, set up a layout that has your graph's layout and the following:

```py
import dash_core_components as dcc
dcc.Interval(id="refresh-graph-interval", disabled=False, interval=1000)
```

Then, in your callback:

```py
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"), 
    [Input("refresh-graph-interval", "n_intervals")]
)
def refresh_graph_interval_callback(n_intervals):
    if n_intervals is not None:
        for i in range(0,5):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            randomfunction(i)
            return plot
    raise PreventUpdate()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Something I did do though is replace the for loop with having the function's parameter be (n_intervals%5) as it worked much better for my specific task (and crowded callback).

Comment: Thanks sudeep, I am thinking to update existing figure's y axis using its layout properties.  How to get figure's layout?  If I use Input('graph','figure') to get graph's figure, then the output will also be figure, which is cicular callback. any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Use State() instead of Input() if you want to simply get the properties of your graph object. However, you will have to define some way of triggering the callback. Perhaps on a button click or any other property of your graph object.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach in Dash would be to write the figure (or just the data) to a server side cache (e.g. a file on disk or a Redis cache) from within the loop,

```
for i in range(0,5):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    randomfunction(i)
    # write data to server side cache
```

and then use an `Interval` component to trigger a callback that reads from the cache and updates the graph. Something like,

```
@app.callback(Output("graph_id", "figure"), Input("interval_id", "n_intervals")):
def update_graph(_):
    data = ... # read data from server side cache
    figure = ...  # generate figure from data
    return figure
```